# Node lines are not visible even if connected

Tags: sculpting, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I am learning about Geometry nodes and shader editor but when i connect nodes to add textures it gets non-visible soon after getting connected. This thing may confuse me if there are many multi geometry node graphs or shader editor graphs. I have not played with Blender's settings. What you guys think i am doing wrong?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a potential bug - possibly related to your video card drivers. Can you add some images to your question to make it clear what’s happening (show it connected then later when it’s no longer connected). Does it still work as if it’s still connected or is it as if those links bo longer exist? Does moving or selecting nodes make them reappear?

Comment: Moving or selecting those Nodes make them appear but same is not the case when those are connected.

Comment: Check of there are any updates available to your graphics card drivers. Failing that, update your question with detail of your hardware (as much detail as you can) and what Blender version you are using (maybe even try some different versions), graphics card driver versions, etc. Perhaps someone has similar hardware and versions and can replicate the problem.

Comment: Here i want to clarify that i have no graphic card attached with my i5 2nd cpu 12 GB RAM and SSD, I thought when i will be able enough to create complex objects and scenes ready for animation then i will buy Graphic Card. 2GB possibly cz i am low on budget.

Comment: Ok, so no *dedicated* graphics card so must be integrated with motherboard. I see your screenshots you’re using Windows. Go into control panel and see what Display Adapter drivers you are using. If all else fails you should raise a Blender Bug Report, including all the details you can (there’s an option in the main Blender menu to report a bug).

Comment: When i try to update my graphic display driver it says the best driver  Intel HD Graphics (9.17.10.4459  5/19/2016)  for your device is already installed.