# Blender is becoming increasingly unresponsive and Vanished line nodes

Tags: node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, shader-nodes

I am facing following 2 problems.
My blender works fine on modelling and sculpting. But when i try to create new materials it starts helding/irresponsive and takes 5- 10 minutes to responding and quite often gets crashed. Blender version is 2.93.1
It already [don't show Node lines](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/229505/node-lines-are-not-visible-even-if-connected) which i had posted in another question here a few weeks back.

People said it is a bug so i reported it to blender. To solve my problem i tried different versions of Blender from previous to Beta but it did not help and also tried to change screen resolutions but still node lines get disaapeared once those are connected, i have explained this particular issue in detail in my former question. So, I am convinced that there is no bug but some issue on my end which i am unable to understand/diagnose.

My System Specifications are:
i5 2400
4 core 4 thread
12 GB RAM
SSD installed.
Later Graphic Drivers of intel are already installed.
I have no Graphic Card attached.

Comment: It may still be an issue with your hardware/drivers, which makes it unsuitable for this site, I'm afraid...

Comment: This is what i fear too. Thinking of buying Xeon e5 2670 duel processor and then see how it fares