# Node Connections Not Visible

Tags: node-editor

I'm having an issue with node connections not showing up at all in the shading editor and I'm using blender 2.93.5. My graphics driver did need updating so I did, but that doesn't seem to have changed anything. Do I just need a better graphics card, or might there be something else going on?

[image: Screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you please share your file as well? This looks pretty weird, because if there would be no connection, your cube would be black, but if it is pink it means that there is texture missing even though you are using no texture in this material

Comment: i could reproduce his behaviour if you plugin volume(or surface) AND displacement, it will be pink. Although i don't now why.... ;)

Comment: This seems to be related to https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/229505/29586

Comment: Please add your blend file ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: I've added the blend file. I thought it had to be doing something since it turned pink, I just didn't know what. If it helps I have an AMD Radeon R9 200 Series graphics card and am running windows 10.

Comment: This isn't any kind of resolution, but just info for others: on a Windows 10 GTX 1080, when I open your .blend in either 2.83.2 or 2.90 Alpha (don't have 2.93.5 handy at the moment), in both cases I see node connections---but the node connections involve the BSDF output being plugged into both Surface and Displacement, with the Displacement connection edge colored red to highlight that it is possibly of an unexpected type. Removing that edge yields normal shading. (But obviously this doesn't explain why you don't have edges at all in your shader editor.)

Comment: Downloaded 2.93.5 -- exactly the same behavior there.